# URI 1021 dá erro de 5%

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, matemática, decimal

> Leia um valor de ponto flutuante com duas casas decimais. Este valor representa um valor monetário. A seguir, calcule o menor número de notas e moedas possíveis no qual o valor pode ser decomposto. As notas consideradas são de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. As moedas possíveis são de 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 e 0.01. A seguir mostre a relação de notas necessárias.
>
> Entrada:
>
> - O arquivo de entrada contém um valor de ponto flutuante N (0 ≤ N ≤ 1000000.00).
>
> Saída:
>
> - Imprima a quantidade mínima de notas e moedas necessárias para trocar o valor inicial, conforme exemplo fornecido.
>
> Obs: Utilize ponto (`.`) para separar a parte decimal.

```
using System;

namespace URI_1021_notas_e_moedas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            double N;
            int n100, n50, n20, n10, n5, n2, m100, m50, m25, m10, m5, m1, resto;

            N = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            resto = (int)N; // não tem conversão de double para int; então tem que fazer esse truque

            Console.WriteLine("NOTAS:");

            n100 = resto / 10000;

            Console.WriteLine(n100 + " nota(s) de R$ 100.00");

            resto = resto % 10000;
            n50 = resto / 5000;

            Console.WriteLine(n50 + " nota(s) de R$ 50.00");

            resto = resto % 5000;
            n20 = resto / 2000;

            Console.WriteLine(n20 + " nota(s) de R$ 20.00");

            resto = resto % 2000;
            n10 = resto / 1000;

            Console.WriteLine(n10 + " nota(s) de R$ 10.00");

            resto = resto % 1000;
            n5 = resto / 500;

            Console.WriteLine(n5 +  " nota(s) de R$ 5.00");

            resto = resto % 500;
            n2 = resto / 200;

            Console.WriteLine(n2 + " nota(s) de R$ 2.00");
            Console.WriteLine("MOEDAS:");

            resto = resto % 200;
            m100 = resto / 100;

            Console.WriteLine(m100 + " moeda(s) de R$ 1.00");

            resto = resto % 100;
            m50 = resto / 50;

            Console.WriteLine(m50 + " moeda(s) de R$ 0.50");

            resto = resto % 50;
            m25 = resto / 25;

            Console.WriteLine(m25 + " moeda(s) de R$ 0.25");

            resto = resto % 25;
            m10 = resto / 10;

            Console.WriteLine(m10 + " moeda(s) de R$ 0.10");

            resto = resto % 10;
            m5 = resto / 5;

            Console.WriteLine(m5 + " moeda(s) de R$ 0.05");

            resto = resto % 5;
            m1 = resto;

            Console.WriteLine(m1 + " moeda(s) de R$ 0.01");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jogue a tua saida aqui, veja se esta igual do site do uri

Comment: Enviei de novo e a saída está igualzinha a do URI... não sei o que está acontecendo... muito obrigado, Gabriella

Comment: funcionou? de nada =D

Comment: @JairoGarciaPereira Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O código é um pouco confuso e tem alguns erros. Eu consertei o erro da falta de validação porque é o certo a se fazer mesmo que passe no exercício. Usei [`decimal` que é o tipo correto para valores monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Reduzi a complexidade eliminando tudo o que não era necessário e modernizei o código.

Não é verdade que não tem como converter `double` ou `decimal` de outras formas, mas o uso de *cast* neste caso parece adequado.

Há um erro que você não fez a normalização para transformar centavos em inteiros, para isto deveria ter multiplicado por 100.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n)) return;
        var resto = (int)(n * 100);
        WriteLine("NOTAS:");
        WriteLine($"{resto / 10000} nota(s) de R$ 100.00");
        resto %= 10000;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 5000} nota(s) de R$ 50.00");
        resto %= 5000;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 2000} nota(s) de R$ 20.00");
        resto %= 2000;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 1000} nota(s) de R$ 10.00");
        resto %= 1000;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 500} nota(s) de R$ 5.00");
        resto %= 500;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 200} nota(s) de R$ 2.00");
        WriteLine("MOEDAS:");
        resto %= 200;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 100} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00");
        resto %= 100;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 50} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50");
        resto %= 50;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 25} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25");
        resto %= 25;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 10} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10");
        resto %= 10;
        WriteLine($"{resto / 5} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05");
        resto %= 5;
        WriteLine($"{resto} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qqoaTG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EJvTur). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/CountMoney.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Muitas vezes apenas um espaço pode causar erro e não ser aceito, acredito que você esteja com espaço a mais.
Este é o meu código do problema em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {

    double Valor;
    int moedas, c, notas;
    scanf("%lf", &Valor);
    c = Valor * 100;
    c = c / 100;
    printf("NOTAS:\n");
    notas = c / 100;
    c = c - notas * 100;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", notas); 
    notas = c / 50;
    c = c - notas * 50;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", notas);
    notas = c / 20;
    c = c - notas * 20;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", notas);
    notas = c / 10;
    c = c - notas * 10;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", notas);
    notas = c / 5;
    c = c - notas * 5;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", notas);
    notas = c / 2;
    c = c - notas * 2;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", notas);
    notas = c / 1;

    c = Valor * 100;
    c = c % 100;

    printf("MOEDAS:\n");
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n", notas);
    moedas = c / 50;
    c = c - moedas * 50;
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n", moedas);
    moedas = c / 25;
    c = c - moedas * 25;
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", moedas);
    moedas = c / 10;
    c = c - moedas * 10;
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n", moedas);
    moedas = c / 5;
    c = c - moedas * 5;
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n", moedas);
    moedas = c / 1;
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n", moedas); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O código é C# e não C.

Comment: sim eu sei estava mostrando o meu para ele, ainda falei isso. Sou nova aqui se tiver errada pode me corrigir, mas acho que aqui é para ajudarmos as pessoas não darmos tudo pronto, ele nao mostrou o código dele só o que printa por ultimo, por isso também pedi para que mostrasse a saída.

Comment: Aqui no SOpt a gente preza por respostas que sejam adequadas ao que a pessoa perguntou, que sejam corretas, resolvam o problema e tenham qualidade. Postagens que são só para a pessoas ver algo diferente e quem sabe ajudar não são adequadas. Ele postou o código dele em C# e tem um erro específico para ser corrigido, conforme eu fiz na minha resposta. Eu melhorei o código dele, que é algo opcional, mas o principal é que corrigi o único erro que tinha no código C#.

Comment: ok,  desculpe se fui inconveniente, só estava querendo ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

fiz meu codigo e deu certo (c#)

double N, x, y, nota100, nota50, nota20, nota10, nota5, nota2, moeda1, moeda50, moeda25, moeda10, moeda05, moeda01;

```
            N = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            x = Math.Floor(N);
            y = N - x;
            y *= 100;

            nota100 = (int) x / 100;
            nota50 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100)) / 50;
            nota20 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100) - (nota50 * 50)) / 20;
            nota10 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100) - (nota50 * 50) - (nota20 * 20)) / 10;
            nota5 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100) - (nota50 * 50) - (nota20 * 20) - (nota10 * 10)) / 5;
            nota2 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100) - (nota50 * 50) - (nota20 * 20) - (nota10 * 10) - (nota5 * 5)) / 2;
            moeda1 = (int) (x - (nota100 * 100) - (nota50 * 50) - (nota20 * 20) - (nota10 * 10) - (nota5 * 5) - (nota2 * 2));

            moeda50 = (int) y / 50;
            moeda25 = (int) (y - (moeda50 * 50)) / 25;
            moeda10 = (int) (y - (moeda50 * 50) - (moeda25 * 25)) / 10;
            moeda05 = (int) (y - (moeda50 * 50) - (moeda25 * 25) - (moeda10 * 10)) / 5;
            moeda01 = (int) (y - (moeda50 * 50) - (moeda25 * 25) - (moeda10 * 10) - (moeda05 * 5));



            Console.WriteLine("NOTAS:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 100.00", nota100);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 50.00", nota50);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 20.00", nota20);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 10.00", nota10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 5.00", nota5);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 2.00", nota2);
            Console.WriteLine("MOEDAS:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00", moeda1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50", moeda50);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25", moeda25);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10", moeda10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05", moeda05);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01", moeda01);
```